# oauth application for msn domain name for call back url

Tags: oauth, dns, localhost, msn, scribe

i am doing a project on oauth for different providers.MSN live is one of them.

i have used the scribe oauth code for all of the providers. For google,twitter,facebook,linkedin i am able to get the callback url as http://localhost:8080/ and it is returning well with the verification code.

But with the MSN it is asking the domain name(it is not allowing me to type the localhost:url and it is asking clerly that i should give valid domain name while in registration.

So i gave my blogsite name as valid url.

when i run my application i am getting callback as http:myname.blogspot.in/code="somecode"

Now i should use the code dyanamically in programming to verify the code so that i get the user resources.

Alternatively can we change our localhost application to domain application so that in the registration of the msn site also it should show valid domain and we can get the data from msn to our localhost application.

Some steps are given in the following link

http://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/how-to-change-localhost-to-a-domain-name

But the fake url (means the localhost application which is converted as domain url).....can it be identified by msn as valid domain is still not understandable.

if anybody has some knowledge on this, can you some light on this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes i got it.......it is working fine..Thank you..

Comment: Can you please answer/close/delete this question if it's already solved?

Comment: @ Pablo...i could do that.But i am not allowed to write answer before 8 hours i asked question.i have one small question.i have been searching on the protected resource url for msn live...can you please help me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple after Mr.Umesh Awasthi gave the clue.

Firstly,go to the below site.

http://24sevenpost.com/tech-gizmo/windows-7-step-step-guide-edit-hosts-file-system32/

take a new line the hosts file and type like this.

127.0.0.1  www.babc.com

then you have your own domain.

Give the domain name as http://www.babc.com:8080/ in the registration form domain name text box.

Thats it.

run the apache tomcat

run the application.

you will get a message like this. www.babc.com:8080/code="somecode"

Thank you.

But i have small problem. i have to give the Url for protected resources.

i have tried with giving the url as https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me

```
400
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

i do not understand what the problem exactly is.Is my urls for resources not a correct urls?

can anybody help me in this......

Comment: I got it..the program is having one small mistake.change the 52 line like this. OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL)